# Duplicate key entry in database. alert the user about it

Tags: java, dao

How to alert a user when an exception is caught in java file on the jsp page? Like we do in java script. I am cathching a duplicate key exception in java DAO file.

Comment: throw using validator or exception handler.

Comment: Why not prevent duplicate keys? AutoIncrement of a primary key should be able to help you out.

Comment: No I have composite keys. I want user to enter everything.

Answer (score 0):

You an set an attribute in DAO java file which holds the alert message and straight away you can use it inside JSP within scriplet tags ( Ex: <%= dao.attributeName %>)

Comment: attribute as in a variable of string type? that I can use as                         <% DashboardDAO.abc %>

Comment: @leharbhatt yes, and the specific DAO java file have to be imported in your JSP

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate key entry on database level? your database isn't design well. But the question isn't about it. As you are focusing on client notification as created/duplicate messages please follow [THIS LINK](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MYFACES/Displaying+Errors+-+Infos+-+Warnings+in+JSF+pages)
In your case
Displaying Message:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" prefix="h"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" prefix="f"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk" prefix="t"%>

<h:panelGrid styleClass="group" columns="2" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" width="100%" columnClasses="buttonCol, leftAlignCol" rowClasses="vertAlignTop" rendered="#{! empty facesContext.maximumSeverity}" >
    <h:graphicImage value="#{PageMessages.messageImage}" style="float: left; vertical-align: top;" />
    <h:panelGrid columns="1" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" columnClasses="leftAlignCol" rowClasses="vertAlignTop" width="100%">
        <h:outputText value="#{PageMessages.messageHeader}" escape="false" rendered="#{PageMessages.renderMessage}"/>
        <h:messages errorClass="errorMessage" infoClass="infoMessage" layout="table" globalOnly="true" showDetail="false" showSummary="true"/>
    </h:panelGrid>
</h:panelGrid>
```

Bean:

```
public static final FacesMessage.Severity SEVERITY_ERROR = new Severity("Error", 3);

protected void setErrorMessage(String summary) {
 getFacesContext().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, summary, null));}
```

CALLING:

```
FacesMessage facesMessage = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_WARN, message, null);

    setErrorMessage(Messages.getString("DUPLICATE_DATABASE_ERROR"));
```

Comment: It is completely untrue to say that the database is not designed well if it throws duplicate key exceptions.  These exceptions can be thrown if there is a "unique index" whose uniqueness the new tuple would violate.  Enforcing key uniqueness at the database level is a sign of good database design, not bad.

Comment: Let the user insert Primary key is not right in my point of view, there should be auto increment or Max()+1 mechanism to prevent that. for composite primary key, System should check first is it is insert-able by querying dependencies if not valid than respond to client without any insert query (because it is expensive operation). Otherwise, if and only if user input is insert-able only than insert query should run

Comment: First up, it's not necessarily the primary key; it could be a key induced by an index.  These can throw the same kind of exception.  Secondly, there are plenty of well-designed databases out there that don't have an auto-increment field - often, some field or combination of fields with a business meaning makes a perfectly good primary key.